# CodeDeploy does not change files when deployed with no errors in deployment

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

So I'm using CodePipeline and CodeDeploy to update my instance, but it doesn't seem to work. There are no errors with the deployment process, and the script is obviously being run, but there is no change to my files. My script just does a pull from GitHub to update the submodules, and it works when I run it myself. However, when CodeDeploy runs the script, it takes the right amount of time but makes no changes. Please help!

Comment: Hi @James Kor. Have you tried adding debug dummy lines in your deployment script? something like echoing or creating a file would be useful to check if the script is actually being run or not.